# MySqlBulkLoader not loading data into mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql

the c# code below is not loading data into mysql table. it loads first row of csv if i put Numberoflinestoskip to 0 which is useless as first row are column names. i have looked over google very much but couldn't find answer.

```
var bulkcopy = new MySqlBulkLoader((MySqlConnection)myConnection);
                bulkcopy.TableName = "sap.loadtable";
                bulkcopy.FieldTerminator = ",";
                bulkcopy.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
                bulkcopy.FileName = "c:/test.csv";
                bulkcopy.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
                var inserted = bulkcopy.Load();
```

Comment: Have you checked if the line terminator really is "\r\n" - sometimes it is just "\n". If that is the case the file would appear to have just one line when being parsed.

Comment: does not work even if i change it to "\n". so frustrating. spent lot of hours working on this.

Comment: I would find a utility that allows you to look at the actual file contents in hexadecimal format - check what the actual line terminator is as the symptoms you describe suggest that the bulk copier is only seeing a single line. Have you tried other variations - just "\r" and "\n\r". Are you sure the file is saved in simple ASCII format or could it be using an extended character set - if the latter then you may need to set the CharacterSet property. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlBulkLoader.htm